# Как программно задать размер кнопки = wrap_content?

Tags: android, java

Всем доброго вечера пятницы! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как задать программно размер кнопки `"Wrap_content"`? Если для задания размера в пикселях проблем нет (`btn1.setWidth(1)`), то `"wrapcontent"` я не знаю как задать.

Comment: Через LayoutParams надо задавать.

Comment: Можно подробней, как размер кнопки задавать через LayoutParams?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По-моему, как-то так:

```
Button button;
//findViewById(...)
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = button.getLayoutParams();
params.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT; // или в пикселях
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
btn1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(1, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Answer (score 1):

В java все числа имеют знак (нету unsigned типов), так как размер элемента не может быть отрицательным, то отрицательные числа в переменной (отвечающей за размер) не используются. Потому в андроиде они используются для указания логического размера `MATCH_PARENT` и `WRAP_CONTENT`, то есть `-1` и `-2` соответственно. Однако указывать напрямую размер как `-1` неудобно и непонятно (ищем в Инете термин "магические константы"), поэтому они объявлены в классе `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` как константы.

Для использования просто передавайте их как размер `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT`.

Также напоминаю, что информация о том, как расположить элемент, хранится в объекте `LayoutParams`, который хранится внутри элемента, и у каждого лайоута `LayoutParams` свой со своими специфичными параметрами, но все они наследуются от `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` (и иногда от его потомков). Потому учитывайте, какой конкретно `LayoutParams` вы передаёте в элемент и в каком лайоуте реально находится ваш элемент.

Ну, для совершенствования почитайте http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom.html

Answer (score 0):

Делайте так:

```
LayoutParams params=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
btn1.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Ругается на Button, предлагая импортировать другой класс, вот скрин: https://yadi.sk/i/YTmyzoO3cZTLm

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Теперь приложение крашится при запуске=)

Comment: Падает скорее всего по NullPointerException из-за mContext;

Ща обновлю ответ, должно будет получиться, если ваша кнопка в коде: "btn1"